# python - Tumblr API Tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, tags, tumblr

I am working on a bot using the Python-3-compatible Tumblr API, tumblpy, and I can't figure out how to add tags to an API post. The code posts the post, but no tags show up.

```
post = client.post('post', blog_url=blog_url, params={
    'type':'text',
    'state':'published',
    'tags':['test'],
    'body':'Tag Test'
    }
)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I took out the square brackets and it worked, but I want to add multiple tags, and I can't figure that out. If I try

```
'tags':'test',
```

It works, but if I try

```
'tags':'test', 'moretests',
```

I get a traceback error.

Edit2: I would like to note that tumblpy uses the same format as the regular Tumblr API.

Solved: I just had to add commas INSIDE the string.

Comment: I have used https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr  for blog posting . It may be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, pytumblr cannot be used with python 3. It was developed for python 2. I would just get a traceback error that says that the helper module doesn't exist. The only solution was to use tumblpy.